# Spring boot @restcontroller to @controller with pagination

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

This is my first spring boot microservices project,

I have multiple microservices, two of them are:
- microservice-book
- microservice-web

my problem is that, I have a controller

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class OuvragePageController {

    private final OuvrageProxy ouvrageProxy;

    @GetMapping("/listedesouvrages")
    public ModelAndView getOuvragesPage(Pageable pageable) {
        ModelAndView ouvrages = new ModelAndView("ouvrages");
        ouvrages.addObject("livres", ouvrageProxy.getOuvrageList(pageable));
        return ouvrages;
    }

}
```

going to a proxy:

```
@FeignClient(name = "microservice-ouvrage", url = "localhost:9001")
public interface OuvrageProxy {

    @GetMapping("/ouvrage")
    Page<OuvrageBean> getOuvrageList(Pageable pageable);

}
```

it goes on

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OuvrageController {

    private final OuvrageService ouvrageService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/ouvrage")
    public Page<Ouvrage> listeDesOuvrage(Pageable pageable) {

        Page<Ouvrage> allOuvrageList = ouvrageService.getAllOuvrageList(pageable);

        return allOuvrageList;

    }

}
```

if I call directly the microservice with http://localhost:9001/ouvrage?page=0
i've got:

```
Tree
Chart
JSON Input
{
"content": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Bigtax",
"author": "Shaughn Spoward",
"releaseDate": "2004-12-05T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Y-find",
"author": "Dedie Hammelberg",
"releaseDate": "1993-09-25T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Aerified",
"author": "Bartholomeo Bromige",
"releaseDate": "2001-01-03T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Stringtough",
"author": "Janet Crossby",
"releaseDate": "1995-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 5,
"name": "Alphazap",
"author": "Demott Masi",
"releaseDate": "2015-03-21T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Asoka",
"author": "Brandea Di Maria",
"releaseDate": "2008-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Tresom",
"author": "Dona Visco",
"releaseDate": "1995-05-19T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 8,
"name": "Stronghold",
"author": "Kori Pestell",
"releaseDate": "2018-06-14T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 9,
"name": "Lotstring",
"author": "Christean Battle",
"releaseDate": "2013-03-24T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Cardify",
"author": "Caresse Sabathe",
"releaseDate": "1979-09-07T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 11,
"name": "Tin",
"author": "Grannie Daniell",
"releaseDate": "2009-05-07T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 12,
"name": "Bitwolf",
"author": "Theo Smeall",
"releaseDate": "1992-02-12T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 13,
"name": "Stronghold",
"author": "Rodney Montfort",
"releaseDate": "2017-05-09T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 14,
"name": "Greenlam",
"author": "Saraann Parsell",
"releaseDate": "2004-03-24T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 15,
"name": "Sonsing",
"author": "Shea Follacaro",
"releaseDate": "2013-08-13T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 16,
"name": "Tampflex",
"author": "Lazare Bodley",
"releaseDate": "2007-02-16T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 17,
"name": "Konklab",
"author": "Gordon Ovington",
"releaseDate": "1979-10-30T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 18,
"name": "Home Ing",
"author": "Leilah Surguine",
"releaseDate": "1983-11-25T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 19,
"name": "Voltsillam",
"author": "Sandi Crayke",
"releaseDate": "2008-09-11T00:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"id": 20,
"name": "Bitwolf",
"author": "Mickey Charville",
"releaseDate": "2018-08-23T00:00:00.000+0000"
}
],
"pageable": {
"sort": {
"sorted": false,
"unsorted": true,
"empty": true
},
"pageNumber": 0,
"pageSize": 20,
"offset": 0,
"unpaged": false,
"paged": true
},
"totalElements": 1000,
"totalPages": 50,
"last": false,
"first": true,
"sort": {
"sorted": false,
"unsorted": true,
"empty": true
},
"numberOfElements": 20,
"size": 20,
"number": 0,
"empty": false
}
```

but, going back to my web controller with http://localhost:8080/listedesouvrages
I've:

```
2019-11-15 12:35:43.107 ERROR 16336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder.decode(SpringDecoder.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:36) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:176) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:140) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.getOuvrageList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.openclassrooms.controller.OuvragePageController.getOuvragesPage(OuvragePageController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232-ea]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232-ea]
```

The two objects Ouvrage:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Ouvrage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int    id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private Date   releaseDate;

}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OuvrageBean {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private Date releaseDate;

}
```

Do you have any advice on something I'm missing or doing bad ?

Thanks per advance !

Comment: I see you are returning `Page<OuvrageBean>` in the client and expecting `Page<Ouvrage>` in the controller, Is this intended? Also, could you add both objects definition?

Comment: Sure, this is the same object but with a different name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it happens because Jackson cannot instantiate an abstract type. You should give Jackson the information on how to instantiate **Page** with a concrete type. But its concrete type, **PageImpl**, has no default constructor or any @JsonCreators for that matter.

Since you can't add the required information to the **Page** class, It's better to create a custom implementation for **Page** interface which has a default no-arg constructor, something likes:

```
public class CustomPageImpl<T> extends PageImpl<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int number;
    private int size;
    private int totalPages;
    private int numberOfElements;
    private long totalElements;
    private boolean previousPage;
    private boolean firstPage;
    private boolean nextPage;
    private boolean lastPage;
    private List<T> content;
    private Sort sort;

    public CustomPageImpl() {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfElements() {
        return numberOfElements;
    }

    public void setNumberOfElements(int numberOfElements) {
        this.numberOfElements = numberOfElements;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTotalElements() {
        return totalElements;
    }

    public void setTotalElements(long totalElements) {
        this.totalElements = totalElements;
    }

    public boolean isPreviousPage() {
        return previousPage;
    }

    public void setPreviousPage(boolean previousPage) {
        this.previousPage = previousPage;
    }

    public boolean isFirstPage() {
        return firstPage;
    }

    public void setFirstPage(boolean firstPage) {
        this.firstPage = firstPage;
    }

    public boolean isNextPage() {
        return nextPage;
    }

    public void setNextPage(boolean nextPage) {
        this.nextPage = nextPage;
    }

    public boolean isLastPage() {
        return lastPage;
    }

    public void setLastPage(boolean lastPage) {
        this.lastPage = lastPage;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<T> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public Sort getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public void setSort(Sort sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public Page<T> pageImpl() {
        return new PageImpl<>(getContent(), new PageRequest(getNumber(),
                getSize(), getSort()), getTotalElements());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i understand what you explain here, i'll try this

Comment: @JoffreyBonifay let me know if it is the correct answer

Comment: I tried this way but I did not arrive to make it work, but I found a way to make it work , when I send pageable after do a repository.findAll(pageable) I simply use .toList() to transform it in a List<> for the moment I can continu with this.

Comment: Ok, great. Do you lost the pagination information with your solution, right? When I have time I will make a demo with my solution

Comment: Exactly ! I have no more pagination information now

Answer (score 0):

At Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ouvrage")
public Page<Ouvrage> listeDesOuvrage(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer page) {

  Page<Ouvrage> allOuvrageList = ouvrageService.getAllOuvrageList(PageRequest.of(page - 1, PAGE_SIZE));

  return allOuvrageList;
}
```